# The : is not will showen in pdf file using crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have a crystal report,that contains an character (:) when exporting to pdf this character  is change to be like that  " knowing that when viewed from the main report view button  the character :  is appearing normaly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with Crystal Reports, but with the export file,you need to verify that you are using a fonts available for the export file such as an Adobe Acrobat PDF file.  Otherwise, the characters will not be recognized and the export file font functionality can only use what it has available to represent your actual characters.